# UML Drawing of Presentation Logic, Screen Navigation, Validation

Tags: winforms, uml, ui-design

How do you draw presentation logic, screen navigation and validation logic of controls in UML?

When a new screen is needed or existing screen is modified, I use MS Paint to get the new screen layout approved. I find myself in this situation of how best to draw presentation logic, screen navigation and validation logic of controls.

I currently use Activity Diagram and Sequence Diagram, and put the hyperlink next to the controls and put a link between these two (control and hyperlink).

Please let me know how can I improve upon and represent these pieces in a better way.

I work in windows based application.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid `StackOverflow` question, you probably need to post it on [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) . `StackOverflow` is specific to code related problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notwithstanding whether it belongs here or not, a couple of possibilities:

- [IFML](http://www.ifml.org/), the Interaction Flow Modeling Language.  Recently adopted UML notation for modelling user interface flow & content
- Jesse James Garrett's [visual vocabulary](http://www.jjg.net/ia/visvocab/) which covers similar ground, albeit isn't endorsed by the OMG or any other standards body afaik.

hope that helps.

Comment: thanks @sfinnie, it is definitely helpful. I will take a look at both the links provided.